# Telerik RadMenu: Save information from last item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radmenu

I'm dealing with a form split into tabs in a RadMenu.  I need to save the information entered on a tab when the user leaves it.  I know there's an ItemClick event for RadMenu, but is there a way to capture the information on the previous tab with that event?

I'm using VB.NET, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that this is RadMenu and not RadTabStrip? 
It would make more sense to be the tabstrip.

There is a nice demo that demonstrates this approach with tabstrip:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/application-scenarios/wizard/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: It's definitely a RadMenu.  Code doesn't lie.
I didn't make it; I just need to add functionality to it.  I'd like to avoid ripping it out and redoing it, if possible.

Comment: Depending on the exact requirements you can save the state of the previous tab either in a Session object, Viewstate or even database. 

Just make sure the radMenu items do not have NavigateUrl set, otherwise the ItemClick will not fire.